# Trying to impersonate another user to update Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, impersonation

I have an application in C# where I'm trying to update the AD by impersonating another user.

I'm reading the AD in order to let users update noncritical fields like phone numbers of any AD account. In order to do that, we created a new user with permissions to update any AD entry. I verified the user's permissions by logging into my machine as him and starting the program as him, and I could update any user's entry.

I'm using [Uwe Keim's Impersonator class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) and impersonation seems to occur successfully, i.e. no exceptions.

However, tests have shown that I'm actually still using my own logged in user to update the AD, despite the impersonation. I can update my own AD entry just fine, but neither the impersonated user's nor any other AD entry. So it seems that there's no impersonation happening at all?

I tried to verify the Impersonator actually trying to do anything by using wrong credentials, and received appropriate error messages in return. So the user credentials are correct and actually checked against the AD.

Here's my relevant code, nonrelevant or sensitive parts blacked out by [...]:

```
private void SaveToAD()
{
    try
    {
        [...]
        using (new Impersonator(@"<user>", @"<domain>", @"<password>"))
        {
            foreach ([...])
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = [...];

                entry.Properties[...].Value = [...];
                entry.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
        [...]
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        // Handling
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex)
    {
        // Handling
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong or point me in a direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use DirectoryEntry constructor to establish your ADSI connection as the user you want to impersonate (assuming you have their credentials).

e.g.

```
        using (var dirRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=user object, dc=domain, dc=com", @"<domain>\<user>", "<password>"))
        {
            dirRoot.Properties["l"].Value = "yada";
            dirRoot.CommitChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I don't have all the users' credentials, only one user with permissions to update any other user's data.

Comment: That should be all you need. If you have the credentials of your 'god' account, provide them in the constructor of the DirectoryEntry to establish the security context to the object.  Then you can make all the changes you want.  I hope you have a good mechanism for storing the credentials of your secondary\god account securely.

Comment: I'm getting my DirectoryEntry items from a search via SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry(), so I don't think I can instantiate them this way.

Comment: You should be able to specify a DirectoryEntry as a search root for the DirectorySearcher.  Just set the credentials when you instantiate the DirectoryEntry root.

Comment: That's it, thank you! Now I don't even need the Impersonator class anymore.